# Computing intersection of 2D infinite lines

Tags: c++, performance, mathematics, computational-geometry, boost

I wrote a small program to compute intersection of 2D infinite lines using Boost Geometry

A line is defined by two points in `Line` class. The `getVector` method enables to extract a direction vector.

The `perp` function enables to compute the perp product of two vectors. A zero value means vectors are parallel.

The `intersect` function checks if two lines intersect using the perp product of direction vectors. If true, it provides the intersection point by reference using parametric equation of lines.

Feel free to tell me if you know a more relevant library than Boost Geometry. Any idea to simplify and improve this code ?

**Includes + namespace + typedef**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> Point;
typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> Vector;
```

**Line class**

```
class Line
{
  public:
    Line(const Point& point1,const Point& point2): p1(point1), p2(point2) {}
    ~Line() {}

    Vector getVector() const 
    {
      Vector v(p2);
      bg::subtract_point(v,p1);
      return v;
    }

    Point p1;
    Point p2;
};
```

**`perp` function**

```
double perp(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2)
{
  return bg::get<0>(v1)*bg::get<1>(v2)-bg::get<1>(v1)*bg::get<0>(v2);
}
```

**`intersect` function**

```
bool intersect(const Line& l1, const Line& l2, Point& inter)
{
  Vector v1 = l1.getVector();
  Vector v2 = l2.getVector();

  if(std::abs(perp(v1,v2))>0.)
  {
    Line l(l1.p1,l2.p1);
    Vector v = l.getVector();
    double t = perp(v,v2)/perp(v1,v2);
    inter = v1;
    bg::multiply_value(inter,t);
    bg::add_point(inter,l.p1);
    return true;
  }
  else return false;
}
```

**Main with an example**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Point p1(0.,0.);
  Point p2(1.,0.);
  Point p3(0.,1.);
  Point p4(0.,2.);
  Line l1(p1,p2);
  Line l2(p3,p4);

  Point inter;
  if( intersect(l1,l2,inter) )
  {
    std::cout<<"Coordinates of intersection: "<<inter.x()<<" "<<inter.y()<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: It may be worth it to give CGAL (Computational Geometry Algorithm Library) a shot.